# How to loop through ligtable in Metafont?

Tags: fonts, kerning, metafont

In `roman.mf` the kerning is defined for the Computer Modern Roman fonts.

I would like to write the `ligtable` definitions more efficiently but everything I try is wrong:

```
% With macro
def group_kerning(text L)(expr k)(text R) =
 ligtable for l=L: l: endfor for r=R: r kern k, endfor
enddef;

group_kerning("A", "F", "K")(k#)("C", "G");% wrong

% Without macro
ligtable for l="A", "F", "K": l: endfor for r="C", "G": r kern k#, endfor;% wrong, too

% Less complicated
ligtable for l="A", "F", "K": l: endfor "C" kern k#;% again wrong
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put `for` .. `endfor` loops into `ligtable` commands -- they already support lists of characters.

You might like to read pp.316-317 in Knuth's Metafont Book.  I can't repeat the whole of that section here, but one of his examples might be helpful (I've added the line returns to make it clearer; normally you would put this all on one line).

```
ligtable "o": "b": "p": 
    "e" kern .5u#, 
    "o" kern .5u#, 
    "x" kern -.5u#, 
    "!" kern u#;
```

this defines the following 12 kerning pairs

```
oe (add 1/2 unit)
be (add 1/2 unit)
pe (add 1/2 unit)
oo (add 1/2 unit)
bo (add 1/2 unit)
po (add 1/2 unit)
ox (subtract 1/2 unit)
bx (subtract 1/2 unit)
px (subtract 1/2 unit)
o! (add 1 unit)
b! (add 1 unit)
p! (add 1 unit)
```

So it already supports "implicit" loops, and you can write what I think you want as:

```
ligtable "A": "F": "K": "C" kern k#, "G" kern k#;
```

which is already pretty compact (and I assume that you have already defined `k#` in your program...)